# Javascript code to find the Total number of values between different ranges and also add single numbers

Tags: javascript

I have few lists like this

```
a = [ 2, 47-54, 68-69, 120-121, 318, 320, 342, 364-366, 414-422, 503-505, 513-514, 529, 554, 586, 690, 775, 913, 1018, 1117, 1159, 1183, 1218-1219, 1379, 1478, 1491, 1497, 1510, 1562, 1601, 1664, 1673, 1686, 1692, 1710, 1759-1765, 1862-1881, 1951-1962, 1992, 2020 ]

b = [ 18, 28, 34-35, 58-84, 110-137, 139-191, 193-272 ]
value of b = 192
```

Trying to get a simple javascript code to get the total number of values between different ranges and also add single numbers as I have mentioned for the value of b.

Comment: Are the ranges inclusive or exclusive?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do, for the first list you want to know the number of values between 47 and 54 ? You want to get a range for each value of the list or add each range of the list ? What do you want to do with single numbers ? If you could provide expected result (maybe with smaller arrays, `a` is pretty long) and a code sample of what you tried (and what worked/didn't) that would be great

Comment: For example lets take list b, where imagine the numbers are lines of code, like 18, 28, and 34-35 are again rage of lines of code which contains line 34 and 35. So I need to find the total number of lines

Comment: The ranges are inclusive

Comment: I think `b` should be 1+1+2+27+28+53+80=192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate over the values in the array using `reduce`, splitting values on a `-` and adding either `1` (when there is no `-`) or the difference between the end and start values (+1 for inclusive ranges) to the result:

```js
const b = ['18', '28', '34-35', '58-84', '110-137', '139-191', '193-272']

const numsInc = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, v) => {
  [s, e] = v.split('-');
  acc += e ? parseInt(e,10)-parseInt(s,10)+1 : 1
  return acc;
}, 0)

const numsExc = (arr) => arr.reduce((acc, v) => {
  [s, e] = v.split('-');
  acc += e ? parseInt(e,10)-parseInt(s,10) : 1
  return acc;
}, 0)

console.log(numsInc(b))
console.log(numsExc(b))
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like this

```js
const b = [ '18', '28', '34-35', '58-84', '110-137', '139-191', '193-272' ]

const calculateTotalNumbers = data => data.reduce((res, n) => {
  const [n1, n2] = n.split('-').map(Number)
  if(n2){
    return res + n2 - n1 + 1
  }
  return res + 1
}, 0)

console.log(calculateTotalNumbers(b))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

```js
const 
  lines = ["18", "28", "34-35", "58-84", "110-137", "139-191", "193-272"],
  result = lines.reduce((r, line) => {
    const [start, stop = start] = line.split("-").map(Number);
    return r + stop - start + 1;
  }, 0);

console.log(result);
```

**Note:** To handle single lines I've defaulted `stop` to `start`.